# How can I work with remote connections when using Selenium WebDriver Plugin with JMeter inside Docker?

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, jmeter

I'm working with Selenium WebDriver Plugin with JMeter inside Docker to test a external webpage using selenium in Java. But when I execute the Jmeter Script (.jmx) I get the next message:

`Only local connections are allowed.`

So I can't test external pages.

When it's executed without Docker, it works perfectly, but using Docker I have the problem.

Inside the TestPlan (.jmx) I have defined the chromedriver path

`<stringProp name="ChromeDriverConfig.chromedriver_path">/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/chromedriver</stringProp>`

The /apache-jmeter-5.4.3 folders has the Selenium Webdriver plugin.

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.4.3"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=


ARG TZ="Europe/London"
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN    apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
    && apk add --no-cache nss \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && apk add chromium \
    && apk add chromium-chromedriver


COPY wrap_chromium_binary /opt/bin/wrap_chromium_binary
RUN chmod 777 /opt/bin/wrap_chromium_binary
RUN /opt/bin/wrap_chromium_binary


ENV PATH $PATH:${JMETER_BIN}

COPY ./apache-jmeter-5.4.3/. /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/.
COPY entrypoint.sh /
COPY chromedriver-init.sh /
RUN chmod 777 /usr/bin/chromedriver
RUN cp /usr/bin/chromedriver /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/.

RUN chmod +x /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/chromedriver

WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}


RUN chmod 777 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is the entrypoint.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /plugins ]
then
    for plugin in /plugins/*.jar; do
        cp $plugin $(pwd)/lib/ext
    done;
fi

set -e
freeMem=`awk '/MemFree/ { print int($2/1024) }' /proc/meminfo`
s=$(($freeMem/10*8))
x=$(($freeMem/10*8))
n=$(($freeMem/10*2))
export JVM_ARGS="-Xmn${n}m -Xms${s}m -Xmx${x}m"

echo "START Running Jmeter on `date`"
echo "JVM_ARGS=${JVM_ARGS}"
echo "jmeter args=$@"

/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/jmeter $@
echo "END Running Jmeter on `date`"
```

This is the script in java inside JMeter file (.jmx)

```
<stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.script">
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.log.info(&quot;Opening page...&quot;);
WDS.browser.get(&quot;https://github.com/&quot;);

Thread.sleep(1000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(&quot;user_email&quot;)));
WDS.browser.findElement(By.id(&quot;user_email&quot;)).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();

</stringProp>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Only local connections are allowed` message means that the [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) will only accept incoming connections from the machine where it's being executed, to wit it cannot be controlled remotely.

In fact I don't think running chromium on alpine is really supported as [glibc](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs) is not present there and who knows what else.

Try doing something like:

```
docker run -it alpine:latest
apk update
apk install chromium
chromium-browser --no-sandbox --headless
```

and examine the output. My expectation is that chromium won't launch.

Moreover WebDriver Sampler won't allow you to pass these fancy `--no-sandbox`, `--disable-gpu` and other [command-line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), you will either have to switch to [JSR223 Sampler with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) or consider choosing another Linux distribution like [Debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian) as a base for your container.